# Using ldapmodify to remove all users from an AD group

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

What is the best way to remove all members from a group in AD? 
The help for ldapmodify doesn't seem to support the ability to remove all members of a group.

I found an example of removing a particular dn using:

```
ldapmodify -h 127.0.0.1 -D "cn=admin" -w xxxx -f modStaticGrp.ldif

Where modStaticGrp.ldif contains: 
dn: cn=group1, o=Your Company
changetype: modify
delete: member
member: cn=jeff, cn=tim, o=Your Company
```

I would like to have a bash script with ldapmodify running a command that removes all the users in a group. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do wth [tag:bash].

Comment: @hmedia1 It is perfectly clear from the LDIF supplied what the OP is and isn't trying to do. He isn't trying to delete either the group or the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ldapmodify doesn't seem to support the ability to remove all members of a group.

Yes it does. See *man ldapmodify* and *man ldif.* Just truncate your LDIF after the `delete: member` line. If no attribute values to delete are supplied, the entire attribute is deleted.

Comment: I was pretty focused on the ldapmodify man page, and did catch that phrase in the ldif man page... but it is there. Anyway, that was what I needed, too easy.